# Lower and upper bounds for the $n$th prime number

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Is there anything one could say about in what region a prime number is guaranteed to be in? A general equation for $a$ and $b$, dependent on $n$, in $a<p_n<b$?

Comment: See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Approximations_for_the_nth_prime_number).

Comment: How tight a range do you need?  I mean you can always take $a=1$ and force $b$ to be so large that there's some easy way to prove it.  I'd imagine $b=n^n$ or $n!$ would probably work.  But that's a pretty weak result.  What exactly do you need this for?

Comment: Please search before asking.

Comment: There's always a prime between n and 2n.

Comment: And there is never a prime between n! + 2 and n! + n.